# How to deactivate an account in PHP?

Tags: php, database

I am trying to make a deactivate account so ...When I click a link I want the account status to be updated in the database so it will turn 0. Every time I click the link here nothings happens it just re direct me to another page this my code for the deactivating

```
<?php
    include "../includes/dbcon.php";
    if(isset($_GET['user_id']))
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $result;
            $status = $row($_GET['status']);

            if($status == 1)
            {
                $status = 0;
                $update = mysql_query("Update users set status = $status");
                header("location: admin_manage_account.php");
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Already deactivated";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: `Update users set status = $status` is missing the `WHERE` clause and is trying to update ALL your rows. You should also use `mysql_affected_rows()` for *truthness*. Check for errors.

Comment: I'm not able to understand this line in your code `$status = $row($_GET['status']);` What you tiring to assign to your `$status`

Comment: Check your database. You will find that _All_ your users have been deactivated because your `WHERE` clause does not specify which user to change `status` for. You must review [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Your code is vulnerable such that if the called URL was `http://example.com/deactivate.php?user_id=0+OR+1%3D1%27`, all your users would be instantly deactivated even if you did fix the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: as @Saty stated, this `$row($_GET['status'])` should most likely be `$row['status']`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was writing a looong comment and you got in ahead again...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I'm on my 2nd cup of coffee ;-) *Speedy Gonzales!* Arribah!!

Comment: I'll let you guys have a go on this. Too many things wrong with this code.

Comment: *My usual:* Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: and sure enough, seems like my comments are serving "some" purpose but has tripped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your problem exactly, but why do you select the id based on the id?

Why don't you do something like "`UPDATE users SET status = $status WHERE user_id = $user_id`" in the first place?

In your example you don't even have a condition in the update statement...

If you want to "toggle/flip" a value you can just do something like:

```
UPDATE users SET status = NOT status WHERE user_id = $user_id
```

This way, true become false, false become true, etc.

Comment: That's just *part* of the problem.

Comment: The entire code is a problem... but anyway. $user_id is not even defined. That code will just generate a lot of errors.

Comment: *Yep!* and OP's not checking for them. I think I'll add my [*"usual"*.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827667/deactivating-an-account-in-php/34827708?noredirect=1#comment57397219_34827667)

Answer (score 0):

You code is not ok on many reasons. But the most serious problem is **SQL Injection attack**!

If attacker put non-expected value to your user_id param, your sql like that `"SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id"` and that `"Update users set status = $status WHERE`user_id`= '$user_id'"` can cause very serious problems.

For example: user_id can be: `"0; DROP TABLE users"`

Be careful with your code, rewrite it

Answer (score -1):

Too many things needed to be improved. You should not use MySQL either. Consider [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). BTW here is an updated version of your own code which should work:

```
<?php

include "../includes/dbcon.php";



if(isset($_GET['user_id']))
{

$user_id = $_GET['user_id']; // I assume you want to capture it from URL

$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

   // echo $result; why do you echo it? No need
   /* $status = $row($_GET['status']); should be: */
   $status = $row['status'];
    if($status  == 1)
    {
        $status = 0;

        $update = mysql_query("Update users set status = $status WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'");
                  header("location: admin_manage_account.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Already deactivated";
    }

    }

}
?>
```

Previously, you were not defining `$user_id`. Moreover, it wasn't correct the way you were getting the status (`$status`) of the user.

Comment: which "should" work. Care to "explain" it? Or have I done that already? Ah yes, I have.

Comment: You should NOT do a query just to get the previous value. You can do something like "UPDATE users SET status = NOT status WHERE user_id = $user_id". Also, your example is not containing the condition again!!!

Comment: @lucian.nicolaescu If OP loves to retrieve the status before updating the database then its his choice. We aren't here to rewrite entire code. We can just fix what's programmatically  incorrect. BTW what kind of condition you are talking about?

Comment: *"We aren't here to rewrite entire code."* - Well you should (somewhat), because what you have now, will update ALL their rows.

Comment: This one "Update users set status = $status" you update all the users, not just the "selected" user.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry for this ;)